# Script to update product prices for certain product types

Tags: magento-1.9, price, product-type

I have a magento store (1.9.1.1).

I have a range of different product types, one of which is "Booking/reservation".

I need to update all these products, so that they have a price increase of £0.70p.

I don't want to have to manually amend each price and I hoped that someone out there had a script that I might be able to tweak?

Help advise or help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to update this from Admin Catalog Grid.

Select the Product Type from the selector drop down for product type (if it was properly defined as a new product type).  Select all the products you wish to update the price for (`Select All` possibly) Then go to the `Actions` drop down and choose `Update Attributes`.  On the next screen simply select the price field `Change` check box and input the new price and `save`.

---

*** EDIT ***

```
<?php

// drop into Magento root directory updateprice.php and execute

require_once('app/Mage.php');
ob_implicit_flush(true);
umask(0);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
ini_set('memory_limit', '2048M');
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);
Mage::app();
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

function productCallback($args) {

    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');

    // set product data from row iterator
    $product->setData($args['row']); 
    $product_data = array();

    // get current price 
    $price = $product->getPrice();

    // add additional value to existing price
    $product->setPrice($price + .70);

    echo "Updating Price for: ".$product->getName()."<br />\n\r";    
    $product->save();
    $product->clearInstance();  
    unset($price);
}

try {

    // get collection of products
    $collection = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id','Booking/reservation'); // define product type 

    // output SQL query for collection
    echo $collection->getSelect();

    // use magento iterator callback to not consume memory for large catalogs
    Mage::getSingleton('core/resource_iterator')->walk($collection->getSelect(), array('productCallback'), array('arg1' => '===='));

} catch (Exception $e) {
    zend_debug::dump($e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, however this sets the price for all products to what I enter, I want to increment the already entered price by 70p

Comment: Updated answer with script that should do what you need (not tested)

Comment: Thanks! got some errors at first, but tweaked it and worked perfectly.

Comment: What were the errors, to help others looking for the same?

Comment: I was getting an exception and then an error dump, I removed:
Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);

and all worked.

Answer (score 1):

Run the following script in the root to achieve the desired results:

```
<?php

// For all product:-
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*');

    foreach ($products as $product) {   
        $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() + 0.70);
        $product->save();
    }
// For some product:- 
require_once 'app/Mage.php';
Mage::app('default');
$product_id =  1, 2,3 ...;
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('entity_id',array($product_id)); // pass the product id's in array   
    foreach ($products as $product) {   
        $product->setPrice($product->getPrice() + 0.70);
        $product->save();
    }

?>
```